# Failure to find mongodb array using node.js

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb

I have code that successfully sends the content in the html post to the mongodb default collection where I store the post and the arrays, I encounter an error `(node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Post.findOne(...).toArray is not a function` when trying to find the array. I've done research and came to no conclusion and don't know how to fix it, I was hoping to get some sort of feedback and possibly showing improvement code as I'm new to web development.

What I want the script to do is find all the comments in the post and output the result in a console.log or to make it a const so I can reference it within the code, if you need me to elaborate please ask, thanks.

**app.js**

```
// mongdb cloud connection is here
mongoose
  .connect("secret", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("connected to mongodb cloud! :)");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

// middlewares
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
//app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));]

app
  .get("/post/:id", authenticateUser, async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const getPost = await Post.findOne({ _id: id});
    const warned = await Post.findOne({ warned: String});

    const getusername = await User.findOne({ username: String });

 if(id === null) {
    res.redirect("/home")
  }

   //This is where I try to find the post and all the array's to reference when the post is loaded
   const getCommentsAll = await Post.findOne().toArray() 

  console.log("Displaying all comments for " + `post ${id}\n\n` + getCommentsAll);
 
//Where I reference when the post is loaded
    res.render("particularPost", { warned: warned, comments: getCommentsAll, user: req.session.user, post: getPost, postedBy: getusername });
  
})
```

**Post Mongoose Schema**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  postedAt: {
    type: String,
    default: new Date().toString(),
  },
  postedBy: {
    type: String,
  },
  warned: {
    type: String,
  },
  comment: [Object]
});

module.exports = new mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema);
```

Comment: you are not handling the promise rejection 1 and 2 the findOne method does not work like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `toArray` does not exists for the method `findOne` as findOne returns only one object. So the correct implementation would be

`await Post.findOne({ ... })`

---

`toArray` can only be chained after a method that returns multiple documents, like the `find` method.

`await Post.find({ ... }).toArray()`

---

**EDIT**

My bad. I missed the fact that you are using mongoose.
`.toArray()` is only needed when you use the MongoDB native driver. Mongoose takes care of this for you. You should be able to write just `Post.find({ ... })` and mongoose will return an array for you.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

Comment: Thanks that was really quick, but I'm still receiving an error ```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Post.find(...).toArray is not a function```

Comment: Thank you it did work, But how would I make it so when the user loads the post each array is displayed individually.

Comment: What do you mean by each array is displayed individually? Please elaborate.

Comment: What I mean by *each array to be displayed individually* is that the array to be shown on the next line after the first array has been projected.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to show to actual Post document first and then the array of comments after in separate console.logs?

Comment: Just the comments of the post, and if you cam please make it ejs if not console.log would be fine, thanks.